# Oracle Import errors

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to make an import of a database but I get this error:

```
Imp-00009 Abnormal end of export file
Imp-00020 Long column too large for column buffer size(7)
```

The import creates four tables and creates the rows for three of them, I guest that when the import tries to create the rows for the last table is when I get the error.

I try to use the "Buffer=100000" parameter in the import command with the same result.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What database version? Can you post the export command used to create the file?

Comment: Perchance, are any of the columns in the table giving you problems of type TIMESTAMP?

Comment: This is the command used by our client
exp USERID=system/***** BUFFER=50000000 owner=INTRANET FILE=INTRANET.dmp log=INTRANET.log

Comment: What Database Version? Are there any TIMESTAMP type columns?

Answer (score 1):

According to Oracle documentation:

IMP-00009: abnormal end of export file
Cause: The export file is probably from an aborted Export session.
Action: If so, retry the export and import. Otherwise, report this as an Import bug and submit the export file that caused this error to customer support.

As as result, a corrupted export file is rather possible. However, if a corrupted export file is not the case then according to:

IMP-00020: long column too large for column buffer size (number)
Cause: The column buffer is too small. This usually occurs when importing LONG data.
Action: Increase the insert buffer size 10,000 bytes at a time (for example). Use this step-by-step approach because a buffer size that is too large may cause a similar problem.

You could try increasing the buffer size 10000 bytes a a time, because as the documentation says, too long bugger size can cause the same message.

Comment: Got the same error. I'm using this command
imp user/password Buffer=1000000000 Ignore=y file=/home/opr/Intranet.dmp Fromuser=user Touser=user Transport_Tablespace=n grants=n Log=/home/opr/NewImport.log

Comment: This message comes from an aborted export file. If it isn't much trouble, you could export again and try with the new file. Watch out for any errors during the export procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the buffer size to 10000000. I had to increase to about 100000000 to get it to work. Depends on the size of your columns.